# Pulling multiple values from select statement in SQL

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

I am trying to achieve this in a more efficiently and elegantly

```
SELECT
  MD.*,
  (SELECT City FROM PostcodeData WHERE MD.Postcode = Postcode) [City],
  (SELECT State FROM PostcodeData WHERE MD.Postcode = Postcode) [State],
  (SELECT Areacode FROM PostcodeData WHERE MD.Postcode = Postcode) [Areacode]
FROM MemberDetails AS MD
```

I can obviously INNER JOIN the two tables ON Postcode but I am having issues when MemberDetail.postcode does not exist in PostcodeData.postcode. In such cases I would still like to SELECT those members but with NULL results for City, State, and Areacode. This is being achieved in the current query but it is very inefficient. Any ideas would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT
  MD.*,
  P.City,
  P.State,
  P.Areacode
FROM MemberDetails AS MD
   LEFT JOIN PostcodeData  P ON MD.Postcode = P.Postcode
```

Comment: Cheers @sgegges, the LEFT JOIN was what I was after

Answer (score 0):

Use an [`OUTER JOIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of an `INNER JOIN` - this will return records even if there are no matching ones on the join table.

> Outer joins, however, return all rows from at least one of the tables or views mentioned in the FROM clause, as long as those rows meet any WHERE or HAVING search conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Surely an outer join is the answer?  Something like:

```
SELECT MD.*, 
IsNull(pc.City,"No city") AS City,
IsNull(pc.State,"No state") AS State,
IsNull(pc.AreaCode,"No area code") AS AreaCode
FROM
MemberDetails AS MD
LEFT OUTER JOIN PostCodeData AS pc ON md.PostCode=pc.PostCode
```